# Is it better to charge a battery to 70% every day, or 100% every two days?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging

:D

Currently I have a smartphone with a battery big enough to use it 2 full days without needing to charge it, but lately I have been investigating about not charging it to the maximum, what helps the battery to last longer in the long term.

So, I am in a point where I am not sure what would be best:

- Charge it to the maximum so I can charge it half of the times. (**5 charges from ~20% to 100% in 10 days)**
- Charge it to 70% but having to charge it every day. **(10 charges from ~30% to 70% in 10 days)**

Is there a big difference between both options? Or can I forget about it and charge my phone every 2 days?

Thanks to all replies in advance!

Comment: never let charge get below 20% and above 80% should be the thumb rule.

Comment: Generally a battery will last 3 or 4 years and then there is not much to prevent deterioration after that. I charge my phone to full by the end of the evening, turn it off overnight, start next morning with a full charge and use it to evening without plugging it in at all. Repeat daily. Works well and now time to consider replacing my phone with a newer model

Comment: Mobile phones are off topic here. While they may share similarities with computers and laptops they often use subtly different battery types.

Comment: A smartphone and it's battery can be catalogued as computer hardware I guess, but okay. Where should I ask this then? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, it probably doesn't matter. As long as you're not sitting near 100% all the time, your battery will probably last the life of the device itself. As long as you avoid resting at 100% all the time, or near 0% all the time, your battery should last for a number of years. Option 2, charging every other day, would offer a minor extension in battery life over a few years, but probably not enough to be noticeable. Batteries work best when they are regularly charged and discharged, and don't sit at one specific capacity too long. Some device manufacturers recommend a full dicharge/recharge cycle every once in a while to calibrate the battery.